# XSLT Record a Position in a Variable

Tags: xslt

In XSLT 2.0, I'm trying to save in a variable the position() of a node that meets a certain test. This doesn't work, I get

> Cannot convert string "\n\t\t\tposition()\n\t\t" to an integer

```
<xsl:variable name="foo" as="xs:integer">
    <xsl:for-each select="row">
        <xsl:if test="... some test ...">
            position()
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

The test should pass only one time through the for-each iteration, and that's the position() I want to capture. Can someone please suggest a way to do this?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to achieve, do you want a sequence of positions? `xsl:variable name="foo" select="1 to count(row)"` would achieve that.

Otherwise use `<xsl:sequence select="position()"/>` to output the integer value(s) inside the `xsl:if`.

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
<xsl:variable name="foo" as="xs:integer">
    <xsl:for-each select="row">
        <xsl:if test="... some test ...">
            <xsl:sequence select="position()"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Of course this will fail with a type error if more than one row satisfies the condition.

In general, you can't put XPath expressions in text nodes. In 3.0 you could use text value templates:

```
<xsl:variable name="foo" as="xs:integer">
    <xsl:for-each select="row">
        <xsl:if test="... some test ...">{position()}</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

but that would convert the integer to an untypedAtomic value and then back to an integer.

A more concise alternative would be

```
<xsl:variable name="foo" as="xs:integer"
   select="row ! (if (...test...) then position() else ())"/>
```